# Spring-Boot using JSP's from dependent jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, web-inf

I am attempting to set up two separate spring boot applications. There are a few jsp's that would be nice to share between the two rather than having duplicates. The projects are already sharing a common jar. Is there a way that I can include the jsp's in the common jar?

I have tried putting them in the `/WEB-INF/jsp` within the shared jar with no luck.

This is how my View Resolver is setup right now:

```java
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: If this is a new project, I strongly recommend going with Thymeleaf instead of JSP (both in general, and because it makes this specific task a bit easier). You also didn't mention whether this a modern jar project or a legacy war project; the answer will differ substantially.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - on this project I'm committed to using JSP. This is a modern jar project.

Comment: Ouch. I know for a fact that with Thymeleaf templates (since they're just regular data files), you just need to put them in `src/main/resources/templates`, and nothing special is required to use pull them from dependencies (see "webjars"). You may try that as well; with Boot, I would recommend moving your files to the default location instead of writing a config like this to override the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Add properties in application.properties file: 

    `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp`

Comment: This had the same result as the setup I had before.